# Did it ever happen that an open source project's leader (BDFL) died? If so, what happened to the project?

Tags: collaboration, community

This question is mostly for understanding the lifecycle and governance of open source projects. 
I wonder, if any large and well-known open source project has ever lost its leader / "benevolent dictator for life" (BDFL) due to any act of nature (e.g., death, serious illness). If so, how did the project and its community handle the loss?

Comment: Not death, but ReiserFS/Reiser 4 leader Hans Reiser abruptly stopped his work on it, but the community is still updating it. Maybe a project to look into. https://reiser4.wiki.kernel.org

Comment: It would be interesting to extend this to "infosucide" as well. (As for example [why the lucky stiff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Why_the_lucky_stiff)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My colleague at the Ballistic Research Laboratory, [Mike Muuss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Muuss), leader of the [BRLCAD](https://brlcad.org/) project (also well-known as the author of the "[ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility))" network testing utility), was killed in an automobile accident.  The BRLCAD project successfully continued as others picked up the reins.

"ping" continues in use as a standard tool on most platforms, but I'm not aware of a centralized "ping" project for maintaining it.

Answer (score 4):

There have been some projects in the TeX world (e.g. [tex4ht](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX4ht), [biblatex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)) where the original author suddenly died or otherwise vanished. The [LPPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX_Project_Public_License) has a mechanism for taking over maintenance of such projects. In the extreme case you have to either fork the project or deal with the heirs.